# Java class implements Runnable, creates new thread, then returns strange results. Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, java-threads

I'm learning about Java and it's quirks. What's going on here?

```
public class myThread implements Runnable {

    String msg = "yes";

    public void run() {
        this.msg = "No";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myThread one = new myThread();
        (new Thread(one)).start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(one.msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Result: yes
No
No
No
No
No
No
No
No
No

Why does the FIRST result return as 'yes', then it set it to 'No'?

Comment: Does it change when you go from `println` to `print` (so that the buffer will not be flushed and I/O is deferred)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `start()` took slightly more time to begin your new thread and modify `msg`, one loop iteration completed before the thread began. After the first iteration, the `msg` has been modified by the thread and `No` is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Your new thread runs in the background while the main thread continues.

There is no synchronization between the two, so the background thread will change the value from "yes" to "no" at one point that is completely unspecified. In the mean-time, the main thread just prints what it sees at this point in time.

If I understand the Java Memory Model correctly, in the absence of any `synchronized`, `volatile` or other synchronization constructs, it is not even guaranteed that the main thread sees the other thread's changes *at all*.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a new `Thread` and called `start()` method to start it's execution. But JVM decides when the thread will be run. Everytime you run the program you will get the different result.

First you get `yes` then `No`. Main thread first printed `yes` then JVM started child thread which changed the value of the `msg` and then control came back to main thread and it printed `msg` as `No` till the end of the loop.

Comment: "Everytime you run the program you will get the different result." - This is not true. I ran it 100x, and it returned the same result every time.